# An orthographic projection has the same front and top view

Tags: 3d, drawing

I came across while reading on third angle orthographic projections. The object has the exact same front and top view - both views are trapeziums of exact shape and size (As shown in the image). Also there is a hidden circle center line right thorough the middle of both of them I am unable to complete the projection as I cannot visualize this object - so cant work out the right and left views? Any help would be much appreciated - p.s. I am relatively new to graphics and technical drawing. 
P.S. the single image represents both the front and top views - I can't work out the left and right views.
Thanks heaps!

[image: Top and front views]

Answer (score 1):

If you merely combine the front and top view.. you get a pretty clear idea of the overall shape. Essentially a bottle stopper or cork facing left.

[image: ![enter image description here]

If you think about it, what has the exact same top and front view? A rounded shape resting on its side.

Comment: Or a cork/plug/bung, which would explain the circle bit.

Comment: Good point.. your'e right... more rounded than a pyramid. @StanRogers

Comment: Ah i see... thank you so much, i guess I didn't think about having a cork lying on its side. Cheers